# Resource pool stats in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-administration

For my project purposes , I've configured an alert in SQL server where the object is **Resource pool stats** and the counter is **CPU usage target %**. When the usage target % rises above the configured threshold , I'm invoking a job to capture CPU expensive queries running at that point of time. What is the counter CPU usage target % basically? Is it the cpu usage by sql server service alone or the cpu usage by other windows processes as well. Tried simulating CPU loads to identify the counter purpose but couldn't succeed as I'm unable to generate significant cpu load to help my observations. Kindly help me in understanding the science of the counter in sql server.